# RDLC Column headers not working proper when EXPORTED to PDF

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, export-to-pdf

With a report in RDLC i had some problem setting up column names on top. From hours of crawling i came on this solution of setting up static row properties in Advanced mode as following.

```
RepeatOnNewPage = True
KeepWithGroup = After
FixedData = True
```

Though it works perfect in reportviewer, but when i export the report to PDF, it doesn't repeat headers in order.

For example if i'm showing student list grouped by SchoolNames,
It will show headers on First page for school "ABC", if the records of school "ABC" are more and extended to next page, it won't show headers but will show the rest records. Now if records of school "DEF" are starting with new page, then it will show the headers.

I hope someone up here can understand what my problem is. It's version 10.0 of RDLC btw